# How to check environment from a class library not using any form of DI

Tags: asp.net-core

We are using Entity Framework to scaffold classes from the database as the DBA creates the database and we can't use code first.

When scaffolding it creates a DbContext class and populates the onconfiguring method with the connection string hard coded into that class, we have a partial class that overrides the onconfiguring and attempts to look at the environment and return different connection string based on the environment. However in the partial class we haven't been able to access the environment like you can from a controller.

How would I check the current environment in the DAL layer being generated from the EF Core scaffold command.  We have no problem getting the scaffold command itself to read different connection strings but it needs to happen in the DAL itself so we can just deploy to live without having to rescaffold first with a new connection string.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Core" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xero.Api.SDK.Core" Version="1.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.hosting\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Why cant you inject IHostingEnvironment in the constructor of your partial class to access the environment?

Comment: I can't get it to resolve. Like i'm missing a reference but I don't seem to be able to add the right one.         private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        public DbContext(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {

        } it just throws an error.  so how can i get to it without DI

Comment: @user174634 Basically, it happens because you didn't inject the `DbContextOptions`  which is required by `DbContext`

Answer (score 0):

You need inject both the `DbContextOptions` and `IHostingEnvironment` .

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using App.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; // this is required
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;



// ...


    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {

        public AppDbContext (DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options,IHostingEnvironment env)
            : base(options)
        {
            this._env = env;
        }

        [NotMapped]
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder){
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            System.Console.WriteLine("*********************");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this._env.EnvironmentName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("*********************");
        }

        // your entities generated by scaffolding
        public DbSet<App.Models.XModel> XModel { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Yes this is what I keep finding but I just get the classic type or namespace IHostingEnvironment not found (are you missing a reference etc)   Is it perhaps I cannot add the correct reference because I need to add a nuget package first?

Comment: @user174634 simply add a reference by `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;`

Comment: @user174634 I've updated my answer to show the complete codes of `using`

Comment: Right yea ok that didn't work because I also needed to add a nuget package to the DAL class but the IHostingEnvironment is null.  Possibly this is because it's a class library outside of the website project  but in the same solution or it's never added to the services collection in startup.cs perhaps?

Comment: @user174634 could you please show us the code of the *.proj` file of your library?

Comment: I added that, I have added the package required. I think I need a way to access the hosting environment that does not use dependency injection because the DbContext class is not in the DI container at all.  Instead when the context is required a new instance is created, used and disposed of.

Comment: @user174634 Did you create the DbContext manually by `new AppDbContext()`? Do you resolve the DbContext by DI?

Comment: it is created in a using statement when needed,  the DbContext is not in the DI services container.  whenever a DB action is required a method on the DAL exists and will have a using(DBContext db = new DBContext()){}

Comment: @user174634 I see. You'd better refactor your code to using a DI to resolve the DbContext.

Comment: It's not an option to do that hence the desire to access IHostingEnvironment not using any form of DI. I'm sure it's possible somehow. Everything is, just not for me :)

Comment: Even if your DB Context is created without the DI, it can be done. (Although this breaks  a few other principles). Anyhow, the class that is responsible to create an instance of your DBContext (I am assuming the controller), you may inject the IHostingEnvironment there and pass it along when creating your DbContext

Comment: No the instantiation is done outside of the controllers and the site. The DAL layer which includes the classes generated by scaffolding the database instantiates, does the work, saves it and disposes of it. So the hostingenvironment cannot be injected at all (so i still believe at the moment)

Comment: @user174634  Here's a dirty way: If you want to use a IHostingEnvironment without a constructor (or a parameter)  and keep the DbContext resolved by DAL itself at the same time, the only way is to use a static property. Initialize the static property `AppDbContext.Env` at startup time.